# vector equation on a three dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry

The following problem was the last one, and the hardest, on a high school test I had recently. I wasn’t be able to solve it on time and now I am trying to figure out its solution.

Could anyone help me? maybe with a hint or even a full solution?

Here is the problem:

> Let $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ be two space vectors, with $\vec{a},\vec{b} \neq \vec{\mathbb{0}}$ solve the equation:
>   $$2\vec{x}+\langle \vec{a},\vec{x} \rangle \vec{a}\times \vec{b}=\vec{b}   $$

---

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Multiply both sides with the vector $\vec a$. You get 
$$2\langle \vec a,\vec x\rangle +\langle \vec a,\vec x\rangle \langle\vec a\times  \vec b,\vec a\rangle =\langle\vec a,\vec b\rangle$$
$$\langle \vec a,\vec x\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\langle\vec a,\vec b\rangle$$ 
Then multiply by $\vec b$

$$\langle \vec b,\vec x\rangle =\frac{1}{2}\vec b^2$$

Comment: Since there are several ways of "multiplying by a vector", you should probably be more specific in your text (although I acknowledge that the maths makes it clear, it's bad style to be vague in the text).

Comment: @Chappers You are right ! But I thought it would be clear in this situation.

Comment: You also haven't actually got to the solution: you're just down to $x$ being in the intersection of two planes.

Comment: @Chappers right ! I consider these first 2 steps to be the key to the solution.  Therefore I left the rest to the asker.

Comment: I think it would probably be fairer on the reader if you pointed out that you're not providing a complete solution, then.

Comment: @ Chappers, I see you are upset, because I got the answer approval and you have the right to be. Yours is complete and gives the solution, too.

Comment: I'm sorry that my tone's not clear, but I am trying to give you a helpful suggestion.

Comment: @Chappers I accept.

Answer (score 1):

Following the general philosophy of "dot with everything in sight",
$$ 2x + \langle a,x \rangle (a \times b) = b \\
2\langle a,x \rangle = \langle a, b \rangle \\
2 \langle b,x \rangle = \langle b,b \rangle
 $$
If we set $x=\frac{1}{2}b+y$, clearly the latter two equations imply that $\langle a,y\rangle = \langle b,y\rangle=0$. Then the original equation becomes
$$ b+2y + (\tfrac{1}{2}\langle a,b \rangle + \langle a,y \rangle) (a \times b) = b, $$
or
$$ y = -\tfrac{1}{4}\langle a,b \rangle (a \times b). $$
Therefore
$$ x=\tfrac{1}{2}b-\tfrac{1}{4}\langle a,b \rangle (a \times b) $$
is the unique solution.